# Trying to replicate a Potlight light appearance

Tags: lighting

[image: Pot light ref]

Hi, I'm new to this forum and have been using blender for a few months now.

I'm trying to get this double cone appearance with the pot lights I've set up. I've tried various things like double light sources and even a emitter. But I just can't get this focused lens appearance.

If there's a way to add a b/w ringlike mask to the light source, I haven't figured it out yet. And I'd like to avoid needed multiple lamps per Potlight if possible.

Does anyone have a straight forward solution for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Cycles, a straightforward solution is to use an [IES texture](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/ies.html) in point lights.

Download a suitable IES file, 'Use Nodes' in a point light's shader, and plug an *IES Texture* node into its emission strength, referencing the file:

[image]

Strictly speaking, your model should be to scale.

[image]

Comment: At the time of writing, you might find something suitable [here](https://ieslibrary.com/en/home)

Answer (score 0):

Those are called IES profiles
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/ies.html

https://ieslibrary.com/en/home

Comment: Thanks a lot! Only 300k lamp profiles to go through! ;) I guess the only things I just discovered is that it doesn't require a spot specifically, and that the radius needs to be 0 or close to it.

But yeah, the IES is exactly it. Much appreciated!