# Light problems with hour glass effect

Tags: lighting

I have a problem with the spotlight. I want an hour glass effect for my lamps. The spot down looks ok for me but the one up looks wrong and I don't know why. It's the same spot (duplicated and 90° rotated). I increased the power from 1.000W to 100000W and I rotated it a bit more to my wall but this makes no different. It seems that the wall is absorbing the light but it's the same, no different.
Has anybody an idea?

[image]

[image]

Updated: I added an Area light and the odd thing, the up light looks also wrong.
[image]

Comment: Is the light being blocked by the cylinder (lamp) shape on your wall? Have you tried moving it up and out of the cylinder to see if that helps? Or maybe move it away from the wall slightly? If it suddenly appears once you've tried one of these, then it could be that your cylinder was blocking the light.

Comment: I moved the light over the cylinder and it's still the same problem (I added the screenshot)

Comment: For ArchViz, you might want to consider [IES lighting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/233076/35559)

Comment: @RobinBetts I tried your link and added the *ies fiel. Same problem. Down looks ok, but when I turn the light, it's like the *gif.